# Firebase event is not showing in Event tab

Tags: firebase-analytics

I have created a event on my Firebase dashboard

[image]

and can see it in Debug View

[image]

But I cannot see it in Events Tab, it's not there and I cannot mark it as a conversation event, as I need to set it.

Creating one from conversations tab does not specify app platform, which I need it to be for my iOS app.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There's an intended delay before the data shows up in the Events page. The initial data logged usually takes up to 24 hours to display and 3-4 hours delay for the succeeding data. DebugView on the other hand, shows you data (from events, event parameters, and user properties) as Analytics collects the data. This is used to help you set up data collection, troubleshoot issues as issues arise, and understand a user's behavior as the user explores your website or app. For additional information about the delay in Analytics reporting, you can refer to this [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html).